# The combined gas law and the ideal gas law

Tags: ideal-gas

This might sound a bit weird, but I do not understand what I am missing!

We have the combined gas law:
$$PV/T$$
And the ideal gas law:
$$PV/nT$$
My first question is that why didn't French physicist Benoît Paul Émile Clapeyron consider the number of moles in his equation?
It is because Avogadro's law: $v/n= v/n$ wasn't accepted at that time?

If this is the case, who completed this equation, and was that the same person that discovered $R$?

I tried researching but I couldn't find any good answers.

Comment: This might be better suited for [HSM-SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Wow thank you so much